# How to pass helper text into typescript react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am creating Input component with React and typescript. I have managed to do input and placeholder, but I still need to add helper text at the bottom, so it says ,,Please provide valid email address". Can you please advise how to add this property as a prop?
I tried to add this like below:

```
import { Meta } from '@storybook/react';

import Input from './Input';

const meta: Meta = {
  title: 'Input',
  component: Input,
};

export default meta;

export const Default = {
  render: () => (
    <>
      <h1>{'email:'}</h1>
      <input placeholder={'Type your email'}></input>
      {'Please provide valid email address'}
    </>
  ),
};
```

but I think that there might be a better way for doing it. Can you please check and advise?

Text will be displayed in storybook as follows:

```
import { Meta } from '@storybook/react';

import Input from './Input';

const meta: Meta = {
  title: 'Input',
  component: Input,
};

export default meta;

export const Default = {
  render: () => (
    <>
      <h1>{'email:'}</h1>
      <input placeholder={'Type your email'}></input>
      {'Please provide valid email address'}
    </>
  ),
};
```

[image: Storybok]

For styles I will update them with tailwind later on.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
For better understanding, I'll leave to storybook documentation on how to create [whats-a-story](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/whats-a-story)

```
// eg inside Input component file
// export interface InputProps {
//     placeholder: string;
// }


import Input, { InputProps } from './Input'

export default {
  title: 'Input',
  component: Input,
};

const Template = args => (
  <Input {...args} />
);

const defaultArgs: InputProps = {
  placeholder: "Please provide valid email address",
};

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = { ...defaultArgs };
```